# how to solve the copy files and directory problem in colab by the command cp

Tags: google-colaboratory, cp

I am new in colab.

I executed below without error.

!cp -ar '/gdrive/.shortcut-targets-by-id/source' '/gdrive/MyDrive/target/'

In fact, some of the files or folder were not copied to target folder.

My questions are

1. how to improve the cp?
2. how to check log?

FYI. I still have 50TB space.

I tried many different folder structures, sizes and different network connection speed.